# Deploy Contract (compiled by Truffle) without using Truffle

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, truffle, contract-deployment

A contract `SimpleStorage.sol` has been compiled by Truffle using `truffle compile`. Its artifact is found at `build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json`.

However, this contract should only be deployed to the Ethereum network when a user clicks a button.

When handling the button click, what should be done to deploy the artifact once I get the `TruffleContract` object?

Can we also get the transaction hash and contract address after it is deployed?

```
import SimpleStorageContract from '../../../build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json';

onDeployButtonClick() {
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const simpleStorage = contract(SimpleStorageContract);
    simpleStorage.setProvider(this.props.web3.currentProvider);

    // How to deploy this contract to the Ethereum network?
    // then get the TX hash and contract address
}
```

---

Tried this code on `testrpc`

```
onDeployButtonClick() {
    const contract = require('truffle-contract');
    const simpleStorage = contract(SimpleStorageContract);
    simpleStorage.setProvider(this.props.web3.currentProvider);

    this.props.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        simpleStorage.new([], {from: accounts[0]})
    })
}
```

but in the JS console, when `onDeployButtonClick` is triggered, I get an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
    at Object.InvalidResponse (errors.js:35)
    at requestmanager.js:86
    at XMLHttpRequest.r
```

Comment: `simpleStorage.new().then(instance => {...})` See [docs on the new method](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/getting_started/contracts/#method-new)

Comment: @LibertyLocked Tried it out, but getting an error.. any ideas? I'm running on `testrpc`. Updated original post

Comment: If you run out of gas on testrpc just give it more gas

Comment: @LibertyLocked Finally worked when I adjusted gas to `200000`. Is there a way to estimate how much gas is need? Is there an auto option for setting gas?

Comment: It does auto estimate gas but I'm guessing it might be a bug in testrpc. It usually works fine in geth without specifying gas though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Truffle contract you can do it easily with the factory you constructed from the ABI.

```
const Contract = require('truffle-contract');
const SimpleStorage = Contract(SimpleStorageContract);
SimpleStorage.setProvider(this.props.web3.currentProvider);

// deploy from accounts[0]
SimpleStorage.new({from: this.props.web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 6000000}).then(instance => {
    console.log(instance.address);
});
```

Adjust the gas accordingly.

Comment: On testrpc, the address of the newly deployed contract returns instantly. Will it take longer on mainnet/testnet?

Comment: Yes, since you will have to wait for the TX to be mined.

Comment: Is it possible to get the transaction hash of this contract creation?

Comment: `instance.transactionHash` gives you the hash of the contract creation tx

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this would be to have 2 contracts. Your SimpleStorage contract, as it is, and a SimpleStorageFactory contract which uses the Factory pattern.

You would deploy the Factory contract which has a function that gets called when you click the button. This function basically creates a new instance of SimpleStorage contract. Something like this:

```
function createSStorage() {
    SimpleStorage s = new SimpleStorage(); // You can pass other constructor parameters.

    //Store the SStorages created in either an array or mapping so you can later list them, for example.

    //Array of SStorages
    SimpleStorageArray.push(address(s));

    // Mapping of SStorages with address key
    SimpleStorageMapping[address(s)] = s;

    SStorageCreated(address(s),msg.sender);
  }
```

Comment: You answered my next question! Thanks for introducing the factory pattern in smart contrats to me!